Can window glass be repurposed as a wall covering?
I am replacing the windows in my house, so I am going to have a lot of unused glass. I am thinking of ways to reuse this glass.
One thing I thought of is to use it for glass cladding in the kitchen walls - a new trend that is described here:
https://alexia-systems.co.il/en/kitchen-glass-cladding/
Is it possible? Can the kind of glass usually used in windows be effectively used as wall cladding?

depends on what effectively means

Yes, they can be used, but you shouldn't.
You will have several kinds of problems, most of them related to esthetics. Either the glue will be visible (cement, or silicone, or whatever), or the edges of the glass sheets, or the plastic sheet on the top will actually cancel all the benefits of using glass... Etc.

So where exactly do you want to use the extra glass in the kitchen? While glass has many qualities, it has the big problem of being very dangerous when it breaks. And the windows that you have are surely not made of tempered glass = dangerous.
Please notice that you do not need the entire sheet of glass to arrive on the floor, to become dangerous. A small shard can get into your foot (or hand, or wherever), or it can get in your food. And then what?


I am thinking of ways to reuse this glass.

You might be able to use a few of those extra pieces of glass to create some fake windows, or some "paintings", or some 3D art - protected by those sheets of glass. Just keep the number to a minimum.


I am thinking of ways to reuse this glass.

You might be able to turn those windows to a local business for recycling, possibly for some money in exchange.
Or someone in you area is just building a house or a barn, and they need windows - and you can step forward to help.


a new trend ...

Please be aware that trends in magazines / internet sites are not the same thing as trends in real life, or trends in your area.
The trend in the magazines is to have houses as big as several hundred square meters per floor - called "minimalist". Is your house as "minimalist" as that?

"igloos are quite unsuitable for the outskirts of Cairo" - that depends on how you define "igloo": https://inhabitat.com/star-wars-fans-restore-luke-skywalkers-igloo-shaped-home-in-tunisia/ ;)

I am probably north and I have never seen an igloo(snow type).  From what I understand igloos are more emergency/temporary camp structures, than a house to live in structure.  They are also quite damp/wet in the summer.

Sorry, I am downvoting as too much of the answer is frivolous. If you tidy it up, I will upvote.

Regarding the comment about adhesive colon I would instead use a glass bit to drill mounting holes at the corners, and use mirror-mounting hardware. But I agree that this is the wrong glass to start with for that experiment.

@brhans: Ha ha :) Igloo and _igloo-shaped_are quite different things, but I get your point ;)

@RohitGupta: I re-read the answer, and I am not sure what is frivolous. It might have a question-y tone, but that is not "frivolous", as I understand the word.
